# R: Monte Carlo procedure by Permute or Sample function to generate null distribution

Tags: r, permutation, simulation, shuffle, montecarlo

[image: sample data]

From this data set, I have all patient samples (69 rows total) assigned by my cluster analysis and clusters were labelled as column 3 "Cluster.assigned", 8 clusters in total, UNEQUAL size per cluster. Other columns contains variables, of that I want to test the numerical variables (such as Age) to see if anything is enriched compared to random by chance.

Now I'm hitting roadblocks due to my coding ability. But my idea is to see the real data as **Observed**, then shuffle the labels of clusters by using sample or permute function, like a Monte Carlo simulation, say 1000 times and call that simulated distribution as **Expected**.

Using Age column as an example:

```
#minimum dummy 30-row data
Patient.ID <-c("S3077497","S1041120","S162465","S563275","S2911623","S3117192","S2859024","S2088278","S3306185","S190789","S12146451","S2170842","S115594","S2024203","S1063872","S2914138","S303984","S570813","S2176683","S820460","S1235729","S3009401","S2590229","S629309","S120256","S2572773","S3180483","S3032079","S3217608","S5566943")

Cluster.assigned <- c("cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster2","cluster3","cluster3","cluster3","cluster3","cluster3","cluster3","cluster3","cluster4","cluster4","cluster4")

Age <- c(61,80,78,69,57,70,60,59,72,82,66,68,70,62,82,80,67,77,74,77,74,74,64,70,74,64,54,73,58,87)

CLL_3S <-cbind(Patient.ID, Cluster.assigned, Age)
```

To see if there's any cluster that has patients enriched in certain age, the null hypothesis is there's no difference in age distribution across clusters.
Now I should shuffle the patient labels or shuffle the Age data, say 1000 times, then I should have a simulated dataframe, from which I should be able to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the simulated (Expected)

```
#I image to use shuffle to permute 1000 times
#And combine the simulated into a massive dataframe
 shuffled <- numeric(length=1000)
 N <-nrows(CLL_3S)

 set.seed(123)
  for (i in seq_len(length(shuffled) -1)) {
      perm <- shuffle(N)
      .........
```

Next step is I will then use the actual observation of patient age in each cluster to calculate enrichment by using a Z score. Say obs (value - Expected Mean)/SD.

Once this process is automated, then I can apply this to other columns of interest and other datasets with different numbers of clusters. I have read something about the sample() and shuffle() but it doesnt really help me solving this particular problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether the code below meets your goal. If I understand your question correctly, what I should do is to shuffle cluster assignments only and then add a new column of z-score grouped by cluster labels.

- `sample` makes the random shuffle
- `scale` is used to calculate the z-score
- `ave` helps to calculate the z-score by cluster labels
- `replicate` is to run the simulation for multiple times

```
replicate(1000,
  within(
    transform(CLL_3S,
      Cluster.assigned = Cluster.assigned[sample(1:nrow(CLL_3S))]
    ),
    zscore <- ave(Age, Cluster.assigned, FUN = scale)
  ),
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

---

**Update**

If you just want to average the mean and sd over 1000 simulations, you can try the code below

```
n <- 1000
res <- Reduce(
  `+`,
  replicate(n,
    with(
      CLL_3S,
      do.call(rbind, tapply(Age, Cluster.assigned[sample(1:nrow(CLL_3S))], FUN = function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), Var = var(x))))
    ),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
) / n
res <- within(as.data.frame(res), SD <- sqrt(Var))
```

which gives

```
> res
             Mean      Var       SD
cluster1 70.21086 68.99152 8.306114
cluster2 70.06915 71.93188 8.481267
cluster3 70.03571 70.19276 8.378112
cluster4 70.12500 68.98867 8.305942
```

**Data**

```
> dput(CLL_3S)
structure(list(Patient.ID = c("S3077497", "S1041120", "S162465", 
"S563275", "S2911623", "S3117192", "S2859024", "S2088278", "S3306185",
"S190789", "S12146451", "S2170842", "S115594", "S2024203", "S1063872",
"S2914138", "S303984", "S570813", "S2176683", "S820460", "S1235729",
"S3009401", "S2590229", "S629309", "S120256", "S2572773", "S3180483",
"S3032079", "S3217608", "S5566943"), Cluster.assigned = c("cluster1",
"cluster1", "cluster1", "cluster1", "cluster1", "cluster1", "cluster1", 
"cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2",
"cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2", "cluster2",
"cluster2", "cluster3", "cluster3", "cluster3", "cluster3", "cluster3",
"cluster3", "cluster3", "cluster4", "cluster4", "cluster4"), 
    Age = c(61, 80, 78, 69, 57, 70, 60, 59, 72, 82, 66, 68, 70,
    62, 82, 80, 67, 77, 74, 77, 74, 74, 64, 70, 74, 64, 54, 73,
    58, 87)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: thank you for your response. The code is indeed very slick, I'm too inexperienced to comprehend it fully. But I ran it on my computer, it seems to be very close to what I wanted. So the output of your code is a list, of 1000 simulations.Awesome. In this list, each element /datatable has its own column of Z score calculated. I think we should use the mean and sd of each cluster from all the simulations, that is, instead of having 1000 z score columns. I should calculate mean and sd for cluster1 using the age value acorss all 1000 tables.

Comment: In this way, I should have a table of 8 mean  + sd pairs for all 8 clusters  from all the simulations. Then I go back to calculate one z score per patient, using the real observed age - mean  age of this cluster from simulation/sd  of this cluster from the simulation. So in the end I should have 1 Z score table, each patient has one score, indicating if he is enriched in his cluster, compared to random chance. Does this make sense?

Comment: @ML33M I updated my answer, hope it fits your objective

Comment: brilliant. It works. I think I will try both of your approaches and honestly, looking at your work is a great way to learn more about coding. I can append the mean and sd of each cluster to my original data and calculate a z score. thank you very much

Comment: sorry this is my first bounty question, the system tells me I can only award you in 22 hours. And apologies I'm pretty much a peasant, hopefully 50 reps can be decent award

Comment: @ML33M You are welcome. No worries, it's my pleasure to help you :)

Comment: also a quick question, should we use set.seed here or no?

Comment: sorry, apart from set.seed, I'm a little concerned on the function calculating mean and sd. The update sums up mean of all simulations by using reduce function and then divided by n simulations. That's fine. But for the sd, sum of the sd then average might not hold right?

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bugging you. So I tried to learn your code and modify it line by line, aim to join the simulations into one dataframe then get the mean and sd. below are my code, and if I set seed to 123, our results do not equal.
set.seed(123)
MC_simulated <- replicate(1000, transform(CLL_3S,Cluster.assigned = Cluster.assigned[sample(1:nrow(CLL_3S))]), simplify = FALSE)
MC<- do.call(rbind, MC_simulated)
Expected<- do.call(rbind, with(MC, tapply(MC$Age, MC$Cluster.assigned, FUN = function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SD = sd(x)))))

Expected == test1

Comment: @ML33M If you want to debug based on reproducible data, then it might be necessary to set the seed. You are right, the average of sum of `sd` doesn't hold. I think the average of `var` should make sense in MC simulation, and then take `sqrt` over the mean of variance. I updated my answer and please check it out

Comment: awesome. haha finally when I put my head into it I'm not totally useless. Thank you for the help :)